# Tempered distributions : why $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\varphi(x)dx =\langle1,\varphi\rangle$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space.

For $f\in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n,X)$, we define Fourier transform of $f$ as $\langle \mathcal Ff,\varphi\rangle:=\langle f,\mathcal F\varphi\rangle$ for each $\varphi\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n).$

And define dirac delta $\delta$ as $\langle \delta,\varphi\rangle:=\varphi(0)$ for each $\varphi\in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n).$

Then, show that $\mathcal F\delta =1.$

Proof

For each $\varphi\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n),$
$$\langle \mathcal F\delta,\varphi\rangle
=\langle\delta,\mathcal F\varphi\rangle
=\mathcal F\varphi(0)
=\int_{\mathbb R^n}\varphi(x)dx
=\langle1,\varphi\rangle.
$$

Thus $\mathcal F\delta=1.$

---

I don't understand the last part : $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\varphi(x)dx
=\langle1,\varphi\rangle.$

I read some books about distribution but those book says $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\varphi(x)dx
=\langle1,\varphi\rangle$ without explanation.

Why does this hold ? Is this the definition of $1$ of tempered distributions ?

Comment: It holds by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a distribution, $f$, acts on the space of test functions via integration. That is, $$\langle f,\varphi\rangle:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\varphi$$ for a test function $\varphi$. So they’re just noticing that $$\int \varphi=\int 1\cdot \varphi:=\langle 1,\varphi\rangle$$ I.e. integration is just integration against the constant function one which is by definition the action of the distribution defined by the constant one function on the space of test functions.

Comment: Not all distributions act by integration. In this case it works because to every locally integrable function a distribution that acts by integration can be associated. Of course this is the case here for the constant $1$ function.

Comment: @jd27 ah thank you for adding that. Yes of course.